# How do you undo a mistakenly overwiten git commit message?

Tags: git

If you accidentally overwrite a git commit message, is there any way to recover it?

Before:

```
foo@bar:/tmp/git-test$ git log
commit ad7edbdf70ca1d7f0069b50726646e235f42a02f
Author: Steve Jobs <steve@apple.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 31 11:46:24 2014 -0600

    Imporant stuff
    1. thing a
    2. thing b

commit aa502ffbd7350b37e040f59f394c0daf97a11648
Author: Steve Jobs <steve@apple.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 31 11:45:41 2014 -0600

    First commit
```

Accidentally overwrite the commit with the message from the first

```
 git commit --amend -c aa502ffbd7350b37e040f59f394c0daf97a11648
```

Notice that I now have 2 commits with the same message

```
foo@bar:/tmp/git-test$ git log
commit ad7edbdf70ca1d7f0069b50726646e235f42a02f
Author: Steve Jobs <steve@apple.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 31 11:46:24 2014 -0600

    First commit

commit aa502ffbd7350b37e040f59f394c0daf97a11648
Author: Steve Jobs <steve@apple.com>
Date:   Mon Mar 31 11:45:41 2014 -0600

    First commit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find old git messages in the git logs.

```
grep -r -i "Important Stuff" .git/*
.git/logs/HEAD:aa502ffbd7350b37e040f59f394c0daf97a11648 ad7edbdf70ca1d7f0069b50726646e235f42a02f Steve Jobs <steve@apple.com> 1396287984 -0600  commit: Imporant stuff
.git/logs/refs/heads/master:aa502ffbd7350b37e040f59f394c0daf97a11648 ad7edbdf70ca1d7f0069b50726646e235f42a02f Steve Jobs <steve@apple.com> 1396287984 -0600 commit: Imporant stuff
```

Rename the commit, by using the -c option to point to the object in .git/logs/HEAD

```
git commit --amend -c ad7edbdf70ca1d7f0069b50726646e235f42a02f
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git reset --soft @{1}
```

will set your branch tip to the commit it had before the amend.

Comment: Why the `--soft` flag?

Comment: @GaryFixler I don't know how to answer that besides "because it does what I want" -- unless I missed something else that needs to be reset here?

Comment: Well, soft doesn't update the working tree or index. This will probably work, as all that changed was the commit message, but I find it confusing in the general case to switch commits and not have at least the working tree update to the new location.

Comment: @GaryFixler As I read it it only the message update was in error -- any other reset option will wipe whatever other work was done.